# Android Work Manager periodic work request not repeating when app is cleared from recents

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, android-components

I have implemented a periodic work request using android work manager, the work is getting repeated if app is in foreground or background.

**But when the app is cleared from recents, the work manager stops repeating the work.**

Is there a solution or work around for this??

Answer (score 0):

try to run the app from launcher or generated apk , not from the android studio ( play green icon ) and see if you have the same issue

Comment: Yeah I tried the same. This is also not working for me

Device : OnePlus 7T

When I open the app again and if I don't clear it from recents, work manager is running and showing a notification